# sending email notifications to all developers who committed changes in a branch - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

I want to send email notifications to all developers who committed changes in a branch. I'm using a Freestyle project integrated with Github. I've searched a lot but didn't find a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

1. Install and configure the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).
2. In your job configuration page, click **Add post-build action** and select **Editable Email Notification**.

[image]

3. Click **Advanced Settings**.

[image]

4. Under your preferred build status conditions, click **Add** and select **Developers**.

[image]

Comment: Also `Default user E-mail suffix` need to be set under Jenkins->configuration