# Jenkins - How to retrieve committers email and use it in email recipient list field?

Tags: email, jenkins, plugins, environment-variables, bitbucket

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve a user's email and use this to send them an email. When a user commits, I expect to be able to send that specific user an email. I've tried 2 ways:

1. Using Bitbucket's Webhook to send a URL parameter. However, this doesn't seem to be sending the parameter at all. Using the Email Extension with the paramterized job works fine when I start the job myself, but Bitbucket isn't sending the email over
2. Using several commands in the shell to retrieve the committers email myself, but I can't use this variable outside of the shell to use in the recipients list for the email plugin

Is there a way to perform this task? Thank you.

Comment: You might be looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58382010/8895640.

Comment: I'm using this Editable Email Notification plugin as it seems like the regular email doesn't take in job parameters in the recipient list. The problem is getting the email address into that recipient list. I need to set it up just for the person who breaks a build. I know there's a trigger for this though.

Answer (score 0):

You can first checkout the code and get the commit for the started build, using below code

```
final scmVars = checkout(scm)

// Current Commit
env.GIT_COMMIT_ID = scmVars.GIT_COMMIT
```

Then use the below command to get the emailID for the Commiter:-

```
def command = "git log -1 --pretty=format:%aE" + GIT_COMMIT_ID
env.commiterEmailID = sh (script: command , returnStdout: true)
```

The you can use the "**commiterEmailID**" variable in "**to**" field of **emailext** as below:-

```
emailext attachLog: true, body: mailBody, subject: mailSub, to: ${env.commiterEmailID}
```

Comment: I'll try this out and get back!

Comment: I wasn't able to look very closely at your reply. Is this what would go in a groovy script? I'm very new to Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, you need to add the above code in a groovy script